# Connect C# to Red Brick Database

Tags: c#, database, connection-string, redbrick

Ive read that to connect to database not supported by C# Microsoft, We can use ODBC connection.My question is what is an example of an connection string in c# to connect to red brick database

Comment: Again, what have you tried?

Comment: i have no idea how to do this. this is my wild guess. OdbcConnection odbc = new OdbcConnection("Server:IM_TEST; ROM:5050; Database:IM_D31; Username:qwerty; Password:****");

Comment: And what was the result... or error when connecting with odbc?

Comment: it says, ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to download the odbc driver of the red brick database and install it.

Then add a DSN (data source name) in

> control panel > administrative tools > odbc

Then set your connection string:

```
OdbcConnection odbc = new OdbcConnection("Dsn=RedBrickDSN;uid=xxx;PWD=yyy");
```